# Ruby on Rails "NoMethodError" with no information

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, null, nomethoderror

ANSWER IN FINAL EDIT

I'm running a project using Rails 3.1.3. I only have one page web page and my application contoller looks like this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
protect_from_forgery

def index
end

end
```

and a route

`root :to => 'application#index'`

in routes.rb.

When I load the page I get this error in a body:before html tag at the top of my page (otherwise the content seems to load fine)

`NoMethodError: You have a nil object when you didn't expect it! You might have expected an instance of Array. The error occurred while evaluating nil.[]`

Nothing shows up in my console where the server is running, and there is no information about where the error occurs.

As you can see, I have no idea where to start looking for this nil instance. Can anyone give me an idea of what might be going on here?

Edit: including the contents of my routes.rb file

```
ProjectName::Application.routes.draw do

root :to => 'application#index'

end
```

FINAL EDIT:

I had the project running in a different folder and recently moved it over. Turns out compass was throwing an error (thus why it was being thrown into my body html tag) despite loading the stylesheets fine. I needed to run `compass clean` then `compass compile`, I guess to make Compass aware of the new path. Thanks for the help everyone!

btw here is my Gemfile

```
source :gemcutter

gem 'rails', '3.1.3'

gem 'sqlite3'

gem 'json'
gem 'rails_config', '0.2.4'
gem 'jammit', '0.6.5'
gem 'compass', '0.11.3'
gem 'haml', '3.1.2'

gem 'jquery-rails'
```

Comment: Don't you have another Rails instance running on the same port?

Comment: @MichałCzapko No other instance of Rails running on this port.

Comment: @Gazler I edited my original question to include the contents of my routes.rb file.

Comment: @ChristopherCortez Have you changed any of the initializers at all?

Comment: @Gazler No I haven't touched the initializers.

Comment: Do you have a layout file in views/layouts (if so, what's in it)

Comment: What version of Compass you use? Show your Gemfile.

Comment: @Hauleth Gemfile posted in original question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that it is good idea to have any display methods in `ApplicationController`. Try run

```
rails g controller welcome
```

and there add your `index` and route to this by

```
root :to => 'welcome#index`
```

**EDIT**
After posting your `Gemifile` I saw where is problem. It's caused by that Comapss 0.11 isn't compatible with Rails 3.1. You must use alpha release. Change Compass version to:

```
gem 'compass',      '~> 0.12.alpha.0'
```

Comment: Will do. Btw, I found out what was wrong. I'll edit my question to include the answer (I can't answer my own question).

Comment: While this is a fair point, it is certainly possible to have a route going through your ApplicationController, so that isn't the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's occurring in index.html.erb file. Please, check if you are running on development environment, instead of 'production.' Then check the development.log file.

Comment: I am running in development environment and the log looks normal. Also, there's no embedded ruby in my index.html.erb right now. (not yet)